# Find the volume of a regular Region in $\mathbb {R^{3}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

What seems like is should be a simple volume question but this ones stumped me for awhile.

Let R be a regular region in $\mathbb {R}^{3}$ with piece-wise smooth boundary. Show that the volume of R is $\frac {1}{3} \int \int_{\partial R} F \cdot n dA$ where $F(x,y,z) = xi + yj+zk$

Thinking this is a divergence question

Comment: Yes, it most certainly is. So what do you get when you apply the Divergence Theorem?

Comment: i get ( please insert randomly generated number here)

Comment: There is no specific calculation to do, as you have no specific region $R$. So it's a more conceptual problem. What is $\text{div }\mathbf F$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Divergence Theorem,

$$
\int \int \int_V (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}) dV = \int \int_R \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} dR.
$$

Note that the volume $V$ of $R$ can be calculated as

$$
\int \int \int_V 1 dV = V.
$$

Hence we want $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = 1$. Note that if $\mathbf{F} = x\hat i + y \hat j + z \hat k$ then  $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = 3$. Hence

$$
\frac{1}{3} \int \int \int_V (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}) dV = \frac{1}{3} \int \int_R \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} dR = \int \int \int_V 1 dV = V.
$$